# Manipulating multiple divs by ID with a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 15 square image divs on my page. One div is always expanded to be the double width (the blue area), as shown in this screenshot. 
[image] 
Now what I want to do is depending on no matter what div you click, to expand that div, and decrease the others' width. I have the code working for 1 div in particular (div number 2 to expand, div 1 to decrease)

I don't want to write the code for all 15 divs, where the other 14 are decreased etc. I wonder if there is a way to rewrite this function that it works for all divs.

Thanks in advance

```
$( "#expand2" ).click(function() {
            if(TriggerClick==0){
                TriggerClick=1;
                $( ".vak2" ).animate({width: '50%',}, 1010 );
                $( ".vakinnerlinks2" ).animate({marginLeft: '55%',}, 1010 );
                $( ".vakinfo1" ).animate({width: '0px',}, 990 );
                $( ".vakinfo1" ).css({"padding":'0px'});
            }else{
                TriggerClick=0;
                $( ".vak2" ).animate({width: '25%',}, 990 );
                $( ".vakinfo1" ).animate({width: '25%',}, 1000 );
                $( ".vakinfo1" ).css({"padding":'25px'});
                $( ".vakinnerlinks2" ).animate({marginLeft: '150%',}, 1010 );
            };
        });
});
```

Comment: What's your relevant HTML?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  http://paste2.org/hbUN2ZV7 Check the paste2 link. This is the first 2, but the other are the same (vak13,vak14,vak15 etc)

Comment: @LuukvanAggelen - Edit your question and add the actual markup.

Comment: Man your quesiton is really unclear but instead of giving ids to links, you cas add a class and call click function like `$(".yourGivenClass").click(..` and inside this function you can use `$(this).parent()` instead of `$( ".vak2" )` to access the div where the link clicked is in and `$(".square").not($(this).parent())` for all the other divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div class="square vak vakinfo">
   <a id="expand"><p>doetwel</p></a>
   <div class="vakinnerlinks"> hi </div>
</div>
<div class="square vak vakinfo">
   <a id="expand"><p>doetwel</p></a>
   <div class="vakinnerlinks"> hi </div>
</div>
 .... so on or 15 divs I m assuming you have 5x3 divs and onClick of one div the previous one will be decrease in width to 0px.
//also change 'vakinfo1'...15 classes to 'vakinfo'
```

now you JS code will be:

```
var vakDivs=$(".vak");
var vakInnerDivs=$(".vakinnerlinks");
var vakInfoDivs=$(".vakinfo");
var expandDivs=$("#expand");
var lastExpanded=-1;

vakDivs.each(function(i){
    expandDivs[i].click(function(){
         if(lastExpanded>-1){
             var lastDecreased=lastExpanded-1;
             if(lastExpanded%5==0) lastDecreased=lastExpanded+1;

             vakDivs[lastExpanded].animate({width: '25%',}, 990 );
             vakInnerDivs[lastExpanded].animate({marginLeft: '150%',},1010);

             vakInfoDivs[lastDecreased].animate({width: '25%',}, 1000 );
             vakInfoDivs[lastDecreased].css({"padding":'25px'});
         }

         if(lastExpanded==i) lastExpanded=-1;
         else{
             var divNoToDecrease=i-1;
             if(i%5==0) divNoToDecrease=i+1;

             vakDivs[i].animate({width: '50%',}, 1010 );
             vakInnerDivs[i].animate({marginLeft: '55%',}, 1010 );

             vakInfoDivs[divNoToDecrease].animate({width: '0px',}, 990 );
             vakInfoDivs[divNoToDecrease].css({"padding":'0px'});

             lastExpanded=i;
         }
    }):
});
```

You can play/change with javascript code to meet your requirement, debugging.

**Edit:** As I can see your HTML code on paste2.org I guess you have only one vakinfo div and each time you want to decrease that one only. You can change the javascript according to that. If any query/problem, comment... :)